# FLRW metric, universe expansion, and the energy-momentum relationship

Tags: special-relativity, cosmology, momentum, space-expansion

This is a follow-up to a [previous question of mine](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/700514).
I am getting myself confused by some basic things in cosmology, so I hope whoever reading this is patient.

The Euclidean FLRW metric is given by
$$ ds^{2} = -dx^{0} + a(t)^{2}\Big((dx^{1})^{2} + (dx^{2})^{2} + (dx^{3})^{2}\Big) $$
where $a(t)$ is strictly increasing with time $t$ and $x^{0} = ct$.
It describes the expansion of the universe, and it can be used as a rough first approximation of the universe.
In this metric, the $4$-momentum of a particle of mass $m$ (zero or nonzero) is
$$ p^{\mu} = \Big(\frac{E}{c},\; \vec{p}\Big)\quad\text{ and }\quad g_{\mu\nu}p^{\mu}p^{\nu} = -m^{2}c^{2}. $$
This gives us
$$ -\frac{E^{2}}{c^{2}} + a^{2}\vec{p}\,^{2} = -m^{2}c^{2} $$
and thus
$$ E^{2} = a^{2}\vec{p}\,^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4}. $$
This is almost the usual energy-momentum relationship but with a scale factor $a(t)$.

By convention, we take $a(t_{0}) = 1$ for the present time $t_{0}$ of the universe. This way, $a(t) < 1$ for $t<t_{0}$. But this leaves me confused here.

1. If the scale factor was smaller in the past, how can we say any of our understanding of particle physics (based off of special relativity) holds valid for the past?
2. How can we just set $a(t_{0})$ equal to $1$? Wouldn't this affect the dynamics and kinematics?
3. I suspect the answer to both questions above is that the value of $a(t)$ is a convention that makes no difference to particle physics. This doesn't seem apparent to me. Clearly the relationship between $E$, $p$, and $m$ are different for different values of $a(t)$. How can we get the same dynamics like this? Is there any proof of this fact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think my misunderstanding comes down to a subtle failure to distinguish between *vector coefficients* vs the *vectors* themselves. When you change the coordinate systems, the coefficients of 4-vectors change as well. This can lead to some confusion if you are not careful. There are a number of equivalent ways of explaining this properly.

Take any point $x_{0} = (x^{0}_{0}, x^{1}_{0}, x^{2}_{0}, x^{3}_{0})$ and let $t_{0}$ be the time of the point. Without loss of generality, apply a translation of coordinates so that $x_{0} = (0, 0, 0, 0)$. The coordinates need to be rescaled so that the metric is *pointwise Minkowski* at point $x_{0}$. The resulting coordinates will be the coordinates for which the usual special relativity formulas hold approximately well local to an observer near $x_{0}$. To do this, define
$$ y^{0} = x^{0} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad y^{i} = a(t_{0}) x^{i}. $$
Note that $a(t_{0})$ is a constant, because $t_{0}$ is constant—it is the fixed time at $x_{0}$. Some simple algebraic manipulations show that in these new rescaled coordinates, we have
$$ ds^{2} = -(dy^{0})^{2} + \frac{a(t)}{a(t_{0})}\Big( (dy^{1})^{2} + (dy^{2})^{2} + (dy^{3})^{2} \Big). $$

Let $p^{\mu} = (E/c, \vec{p})$ be the 4-momentum in the $x$-coordinates, and let $\underline{p}^{\mu} = (\underline{E}/c, \underline{\vec{p}})$ be the 4-momentum in the $y$-coordinates.
By the contravariance of the coefficients
$$ \underline{p}^{\mu} = \frac{\partial y^{\mu}}{\partial x^{\nu}}p^{\nu}, $$
we have
$$\underline{p}^{0} = p^{0} \qquad\text{ and }\qquad \underline{p}^{i} = a(t_{0})p^{i}. $$
From this we see that at point $x_{0}$, the equation
$$ E^{2} = a(t_{0})^{2}\vec{p}\,^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4} $$
that I wrote in my OP transforms into
$$ \underline{E}^{2} = \underline{\vec{p}}\,^{2}c^{2} + m^{2}c^{4} $$
exactly as it is in special relativity.

Comment: Yes, you can always (in any metric) go to coordinates where the metric is locally Minkowski in the neighborhood of a point $P$, and in those coordinates $E^2=p^2+m^2$ will hold near $P$. For the FLRW metric, that amounts to working at a fixed time and scaling out the redshift factor $a$. In effect, processes over a short time interval (compared to the time for $a$ to grow by an order 1 factor) are just like flat space; for long processes the spacetime curvature comes into play and you get redshifting due to the expansion of the Universe.